# How to change uTorrent's port from 8080 to another one?

Tags: setup, port-forwarding, utorrent

I'm new to Ubuntu and still learning how to use it. Recently, I've been trying to install **uTorrent**, which I already was able to do so, but I need the port `8080` free to use run **tomcat/glassfish** and on port `80` **php**.

Briefly, how can I change uTorrent's port from `8080` to another one? I've been trying to find a solution for this issue for about 3 days now. I saw some solutions, such as create a  [utserver.config](http://forum.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?id=105211), but I have no clue in how to use it or configure it by terminal or on properties, that is something hardly explained by anyone.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
/etc/init.d/tomcat7 stop
```

open utserver at 8080 and change in settings to another port.

```
/etc/init.d/tomcat7 start
```